# Filtering Object Collection by String Array

Tags: powershell

I have a collection of objects (tens of thousands) each containing a property containing a file path as a string. These are named $fileObjects in the code below.

```
(i.e. 
  $fileObject.FilePath = "\\root\folder1\foldera\folderb\folderc"
  $fileObject.FilePath = "\\root\foo\bar\fldr1"
  $fileObject.FilePath = "\\bar\foo\folder3" 
).
```

I also have a small string collection where each string is the starting portion of a file path

```
(i.e. 
  "\\root\folder1",
  "\\root\folder2",
  "\\root\folder3" etc.
)
```

These strings are called $paths in the code below.

I would like to filter (rather than use foreach loops) all the $fileObjects so that I can return only the objects where the file path begins with one of the values in the $paths string collection.

The following code does not work but it is what I'd like to do:

```
foreach($path in $paths)
{

   # Get all $fileObjects where FilePath property starts with $path
   #
       $subfolders = $fileObjects.FolderPath.StartsWith($path)

   # Now process the $subfolders
}
```

I have not found a succinct way to do this without foreach looping every $fileObject agains every $path.

Comment: What you are trying to do reminds me very much of a relational join in languages like SQL.  That's not a solution, although I note you have gotten an acceptable answer.  It surprises me that PS doesn't have a relational join operation, although I've seen a few efforts by other scripters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a regex match after joining your collection of paths with a `|` to compare against.

```
$RegEx = (@("\\root\folder1","\\root\folder2","\\root\folder3") | ForEach-Object {[regex]::Escape($_)}) -join '|'
$subfolders = $fileObjects | Where-Object {$_.FolderPath -match $RegEx}
```